# Django-allauth Linkedin OAUTH2.0 Missing Fields in extra_data

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

All other configurations result in login failure(SERVER 500 ERROR). After a dozen permutation of different combinations, the only configuration with login success but **still misses fields** in extra_data is as follows. The missing fields can be 'skills', 'summary' from 'r_basicprofile' scope.

Am I missing some import information? Please let me know if you spot it. I have been reading the source code of django-allauth to understand this issue.

Actually, there are two issues here:

1. What is the correct configuration for using linkedin_oauth2? A full configuration includes login.html, INSTALLED_APPS, and SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS.
2. Why are there fields specified in `PROFILE_FIELDS` not populated into extra_data?

My Linkedin social login app was created recently. So, it is using the OAuth2.0 instead of OAuth1.0, right? I followed the instruction on the doc https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html?highlight=provider_login_url#linkedin   which says 'Leave the OAuth redirect URL empty.'

The configuration that still misses fields but enable login success:
In template login.html, use 'linkedin'

```
  <a href="{% provider_login_url 'linkedin' %}" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
```

In settings.py, use 'linkedin' in INSTALLED_APPS, and 'linkedin_oauth2' in SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS.

I did not put { 'r_contactinfo', 'r_network'} in the 'SCOPE' as it requires 'Apply with Linkedin' program application and approval.

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(
    ...
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #providers
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
  ....
 )


SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'linkedin_oauth2':
          {'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile'],
           'PROFILE_FIELDS': ['id',
                             'first-name',
                             'last-name',
                             'email-address',
                             'picture-url',
                             'picture-urls::(original)', # picture-urls::(original) is higher resolution
                             'public-profile-url',
                             'skills',
                             'headline'
                             'location',
                             'industry',
                             ]}
    }
```

All failed configurations are as follows.
Use ONLY  linkedin_oauth2 in INSTALLED_APPS. Still use linkedin_auth2 in SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS

```
INSTALLED_APPS=(
    ...
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #providers
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin_oauth2',
  ....
 )
```

login.html can be

OR

In my debug logging message, here is the typical error.

Using `linkedin_oauth2` in `provider_login_url` causes

```
ERROR 13/Dec/2015 19:22:48 base 1217 139681546774272  [django.request:256] Internal Server Error: /accounts/linkedin_oauth2/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py", line 55, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/oauth2/views.py", line 78, in dispatch
    app = provider.get_app(self.request)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/base.py", line 38, in get_app
    return SocialApp.objects.get_current(self.id, request)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/models.py", line 31, in get_current
    provider=provider)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
allauth.socialaccount.models.DoesNotExist: SocialApp matching query does not exist.
```

OR
If only linkedin_oauth2 is included in INSTALLED_APPS, using `linkedin` in `provider_login_url` causes this

```
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 329, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/templatetags/socialaccount.py", line 17, in render
    provider = providers.registry.by_id(provider_id)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/__init__.py", line 20, in by_id
    return self.provider_map[id]
KeyError: 'linkedin'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will be helpful to others who may run into this issue. I fixed the issue by change the LinkedOAuth2's token_url which is updated in Linkedin OAuth2's api manual.

Comment: I have a similar problem. can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use "linkedin_oauth2" instead of "linkedin".

```
href="{% provider_login_url 'linkedin_oauth2' %}" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin"
```

Comment: Using linkedin_oauth2 in provider_login_url causes 'SocialApp matching query does not exist.Error', as described above.

Comment: You have to register linkedin_oauth2 to social apps via admin